# Laravel resource give extra parameter to route

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I'm trying to access function in controller using wild cards in route through get call.
The route is defined on this way:

```
Route::get('/somefunc/{alias1}/{alias2}', 'uses'=>'MyController@myfunction']);
```

The route link I'm trying to access is defined here:

```
<a href="{{'somefunc/somealiashere/'.$item->id }}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Click') }}</a>
```

But when I click on the link it gives me extra parameter in the route:

```
items/somefunc/somealiashere/1
```

because of the previous resource define in the web.php.

How to skip that 'items' parameter in the route.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `url()`

```
<a href="{{ url('somefunc/somealiashere/'.$item->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Click') }}</a>
```

Another way I recommend you is give name route.

```
Route::get('/somefunc/{alias1}/{alias2}', 'uses'=>'MyController@myfunction'])->name('somefunc');
```

and call it below.

```
<a href="{{ route('somefunc',['alias1'=>'somealiashere','alias2'=>$item->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Click') }}</a>
```